# 25.02.2021 11:36 (CET) cell value displays as 24.02.2021 18:00 (EST)

Tags: date, google-apps-script, timezone

Hi I need help with this:

I am working on a macro for which I need to get the value of a cell that has the TODAY() formula in it. My spreadsheet is displaying CET accordingly to my location.

When I do:

```
var today = sheet.getRange('B1').getValues().flat();
Logger.log(today);
```

I get:

```
[Wed Feb 24 18:00:00 GMT-05:00 2021]
```

On the spreadsheet I see `25.02.2021 11:36 (CET)`, and in Apps Script, it says current EST should be `25.02.2021 05:36`. The date is completely off.

Entire code:

```
function PrepareColumn() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TheSheetName');
  var dateRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 15).getValues().flat();
  var today = sheet.getRange('B1').getValues().flat();
  Logger.log(today);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two modification points:

1. Use [getDisplayValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue) to get the value that is displayed in the sheet.
2. For `today` you are fetching a single cell, you don't need `getValues` and then `flat`.

**Replace:**

```
var today = sheet.getRange('B1').getValues().flat();
```

**to:**

```
var today = sheet.getRange('B1').getDisplayValue();
```

and maybe you want to do the same for `dateRange`:

```
var dateRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 15).getDisplayValues().flat();
```